# removing a file from a git repo while not affecting those who have it

Tags: git

There's a file in our repo that is user-configuration based, and really shouldn't be in there, except that the first time someone downloads the repo, they need a copy of that file to get started with.

Other than that it's annoying, we accidentally check in and commit our local changes to it, leading to conflicts...so I'm thinking of using `git rm -- cached` to untrack it but keep the local copy on my box.

However, will doing this remove others' copies of this file the next time they pull from the repo?  I don't want to affect anyone else.

That aside, is there a good strategy for initially pulling a file from the repo, and then keeping it untracked from that point forward?

Comment: Why not remove it from the repo in its entirety and have the build system create it locally?

Comment: Why not check in a `config-file.template`, then have new developers copy that template file to `config-file` when they clone the repo? You probably shouldn't check-in files that are meant to be different across repositories.

Comment: @ArjunShankar it's a file generated by our IDE, there's no way to build it locally afaik

Comment: Yes, if you do `git rm --cached` it will delete the file next time they pull (although it will keep it locally for you and mark it as untracked).
You can add that file to `.gitignore`, it will be part of the repo but untracked.

Comment: Try renaming it out of the way, to the `.template`-suffix file @Ajedi32 suggested, add the old path to `.gitignore`, and explain what's up in the commit message.  People merging that commit can just copy it back to the now-untracked pathname, and git won't add it back without `-f` on the add.  You can beat the `.template`'s content into shape as good defaults (or just delete it) once the move has propagated, to introduce the change in easily-manageable steps.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this file to a .gitignore file would probably solve your problem.
After doing this, the repository will ignore all changes made to the file in your commits, but the file will be kept in your repo once it's been uploaded.

Check the [git documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) to see how untrack your files.

Comment: If you've already committed it, git will not ignore it. You'll have to excise it from the history using `filter-branch`.